# How to add a string on the beginning of one column and end of another?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a file like this:

```
head pheno_143
FID IID CURRELIG RET_Summary new143
fam1000 G1000 1 1 1
fam1001 G1001 1 1 1
fam1003 G1003 1 2 2
fam1005 G1005 1 1 1
fam1009 G1009 1 1 1
fam1052 G1052 1 1 1
...
```

I would like to change the first two columns of it so that it looks like this:

```
head pheno_143
FID IID CURRELIG RET_Summary new143
fam1000_G1000 fam1000_G1000 1 1 1
fam1001_G1001 fam1001_G1001 1 1 1
fam1003_G1003 fam1003_G1003 1 2 2
fam1005_G1005 fam1005_G1005 1 1 1
fam1009_G1009 fam1009_G1009 1 1 1
fam1052_G1052 fam1052_G1052 1 1 1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward string concatenation:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1 {$1 = $1 "_" $2; $2 = $1} 1' pheno_143
FID IID CURRELIG RET_Summary new143
fam1000_G1000 fam1000_G1000 1 1 1
fam1001_G1001 fam1001_G1001 1 1 1
fam1003_G1003 fam1003_G1003 1 2 2
fam1005_G1005 fam1005_G1005 1 1 1
fam1009_G1009 fam1009_G1009 1 1 1
fam1052_G1052 fam1052_G1052 1 1 1
```

Comment: you can simplify a bit with  `awk 'FNR>1 {$2 = $1 = $1 "_" $2} 1'`